# Method does not override method from its superclass? android studio

Tags: java, android

I have download this source code from github and copied to my project.  Does anyone know the solution.  Please tell me the answer.

```
enter code here

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Data, IncomeViewHolder> incomeAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Data, IncomeViewHolder>(
            Data.class,
            R.layout.dashboard_income,
            DashboardFragment.IncomeViewHolder.class,
            mIncomeDatabase
    ) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public IncomeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull IncomeViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Data model) {

        }
        //error in overide
        **@Override**
        private void populateViewHolder(IncomeViewHolder incomeViewHolder, Data data, int i) {
            incomeViewHolder.setIncomeType(data.getType());
            incomeViewHolder.setIncomeAmount(data.getAmount());
            incomeViewHolder.setIncomeDate(data.getDate());

        }
```

Comment: This has already been answered [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217168/in-my-firebaserecycleradapter-method-i-cant-see-populateviewholder-method-is-not)

Answer (score 1):

"Method does not override method from its superclass" means a method  isn't a method of it's superclass, but is annotated as `@Override`. In your case, `populateViewHolder(IncomeViewHolder, Data, int)` isn't a method of it's superclass. You can either remove the `@Override` annotation or extend the appropriate superclass